# Short Sleeves or Shirt Sleeves

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I've always referred to a shirt that has short sleeves as a "short sleeve" shirt. However, I've also heard it be referred to as a "shirt sleeve" shirt or "wearing shirt sleeves." This seems like a mistake and counter-intuitive: the shirt has less of a sleeve than usual so why refer to it as a "shirt sleeve" shirt when that's the very thing that's missing?! 
I would appreciate your input on the popularity of one phrase over the other and the logic/origin behind the "shirt sleeves" term.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a difference in the meanings; to be "in shirt sleeves" means that your shirt sleeves (long or short) are exposed - so you're not wearing a jacket, jumper or coat over the top (apart from a waistcoat of course). Like you, I've heard one or two people confuse the terms, but according to the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/in-shirt-sleeves), among others, being in shirt sleeves does not imply short sleeves.

Answer (score 12):

Both terms are correct usage, but they have different meanings.

Short-sleeve(d) shirts are, as you would guess, shirts with short sleeves. To wear short sleeves is to wear a short-sleeved shirt.

To dress in shirtsleeves, on the other hand, means to wear no layer over your shirt - no jacket, coat, etc. "Shirtsleeve weather" would, by this logic, be weather that's warm enough not to necessitate layers.

The word "shirtsleeves" also has a general connotation of informality - particularly in older novels, seeing someone "in just his shirtsleeves" implies that he wasn't fully/properly dressed.

Answer (score -2):

That's very strange. The most likely explanation is that /ʃɜːt/ (*shirt*) is a variant - or mistaken - pronunciation of /ʃɔːt/ (*short*).

Comment: I would have said the same, but I see now that this is wrong.  You can delete this post to take it off the table, if you wish.